# How do edit a string with a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

So this might sound a bit confusing but I want to get a string to make a call with an api. I want to do it in a form with multiple checkboxes. The original code will look like:

`let value = "1"`

so if a user clicks the number 28 check box.
the string will become:

`"1,28"`

if the user also checks 5 the string will be:

`1,28,5`

If the user decides to uncheck 28 while leaving 5 checked the string will become:

`1,5`

That's basically the long and short of it.

I'm using React to do this project.

Edit:

This is the code for the React Dialog box with the options.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Button, ButtonToolbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import './FilterPopup.css'
import { filterData } from './filterData';
import { genresData } from './genresData'

export default function Filter(props) {
    const { title, children, openPopup, setOpenPopup } = props;

    const [filtergenres, setFilterGenres] = useState()

    return (
        <Dialog open={openPopup} className='filterDialog' maxWidth="md">
            <DialogTitle>
                <div className='popupTitle'> Filter </div>
                <Button className='popupCloseBtn' onClick={() => { setOpenPopup(false) }}>
                    <FaIcons.FaTimes />
                </Button>
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent dividers>
                <form className='pop-up-forms'>
                    <label className='popuppart'>
                        Sort By:
                        <select className='filter-sort'>
                            {filterData.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.title}</option>
                                )
                            })}
                        </select>
                        <Button className='popupSearchSubmitBtn' onClick={() => { }}>
                            submit
                        </Button>
                    </label>
                    <label className='popuppart'>
                        Include Adult:
                        <input
                            className='filterchkbox'
                            name="isAdult"
                            type="checkbox" />
                    </label>
                    <label className='filterGenres'>
                        Genres:

                        <Grid container spacing={1} direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
                            {genresData.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <Grid item xs={1.5} key={index}>
                                        <label className='genresLabel'>
                                            {item.title}
                                            <input
                                                className='filterchkbox'
                                                name="isAdult"
                                                type="checkbox" />
                                        </label>
                                    </Grid>
                                )
                            })}

                        </Grid>
                    </label>
                </form>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog >
    )
}
```

and here is a screenshot of what it looks like in a browser.

[image: BingeHUB Filter Options]

Comment: Can you post any code for what you've tried so far?

Comment: @sma I've added the code for the page I want to edit. I'm unsure how to even proceed that's why I asked this question to at least give me some headway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state to maintain the values of the checkboxes. Add a click handler to the parent element that captures the events from the checkboxes. You can then extract the value and `checked`.

If the box is checked add the value to state, making sure you sort the array first. If it's unchecked, filter out the value from the array, then sort it, and update the state.

You can use `useEffect` to log a string built from the array.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ boxes, setBoxes ] = useState([1]);

  function handleClick(e) {
    const { value, checked, nodeName } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {
      if (checked) {
        const newState = [...boxes, +value];
        newState.sort((a, b) => a - b);
        setBoxes(newState);
      } else {
        const newState = boxes.filter(box => box !== +value);
        newState.sort((a, b) => a - b);
        setBoxes(newState);
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => console.log(boxes.join(',')), [boxes]); 

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      <input type="checkbox" value="5" />
      <label>5</label><br />
      <input type="checkbox" value="28" />
      <label>28</label><br />
    </div>
  );

};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.split(',')`, `Array.indexOf()` and `Array.splice()` to achieve such functionality as followings:

```js
let items = '1'

function changeValue(elem){
  const itemsAsArray = items.split(',')
  const index = itemsAsArray.indexOf(elem.value)
  if(index === -1){
    itemsAsArray.push(elem.value)
  }else{
    itemsAsArray.splice(index,1)
  }
  
  items = itemsAsArray.join(',')
  console.log(items)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="28" onclick=changeValue(this)> 28
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" onclick=changeValue(this)> 5
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function to add, or remove a number (index) to/from `String` according to your pattern:

```
const updateString = (number, text)=>{
  if(text.includes(`${number}`)){
    if(text.includes(`,${number}`)){
      text = text.replace(`,${number}`,"");
    }else{
      text = text.replace(`${number},`,"");
    }
    
  } else {
    if(text===""){
      text = `${number}`;
    }else {
      text = text + `,${number}`;
    }
  }
  return text;
}
```

for example you can test it as follows:

```
const x = updateString(1,"");
console.log(x);
const y = updateString(5,x);
console.log(y);
const z = updateString(6,y);
console.log(z);
const a = updateString(1,z);
console.log(a);
```